# Python geocoding name 'latitude' is not defined

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I'm a new in django. I want to 
bulid a webapp to search map by address.(Geocoding) This is my view.py, I want to response to my html file to show the map for the input address. My code shows it has name error at/map/. I dont know the reason. Thanks for kindly reply.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import urllib

from urllib.request import urlopen

import json


def searchMap(request):

     if request.method == "POST":
         global latitude
         global longitude
         city_name = request.POST.get('address')
         city_name_Url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
         address"+city_name
         city_name_Url_Quote=urllib.parse.quote(city_name_Url,':?=/')
         response=urlopen(city_name_Url_Quote).read().decode('utf-8')
         response_json = json.loads(response)


         latitude = response_json.get('results')[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
         longitude = api_response_dict('results')[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] 

     return render(request,'WebPage1.html',{'Latitude':latitude,'Longitude':longitude})
```

The error message:

> NameError at /map/
>
> name 'latitude' is not defined Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/map/ Django Version:  1.8.13
>   Exception Type:   NameError Exception Value:   name 'latitude' is not
>   defined Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\alienware\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12\HelloWorld\views.py
>   in searchMap, line 26 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\alienware\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12\env_DjangoWebProject2\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.6.3 Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12',
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12',
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12\env_DjangoWebProject2\Scripts\python36.zip',
>   'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib',
>   'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36', 
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12\env_DjangoWebProject2',
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\DjangoWebProject12\DjangoWebProject12\env_DjangoWebProject2\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:  Mon, 5 Feb 2018 21:57:22 +0800

Comment: Please edit your question with the complete error you get.

Comment: Okay, I edit it yet.

Comment: Please fix your snippet indentation so it __exactly__ matches your real code.

Comment: I think your variable `latitude` is only defined when the `IF` block is executed, if the condition is not met, its not defined. This leads to the error you get. Define `latitude` before the if condition. (set it to None or similar.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I change it but still doesn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify, dont just copy `global latitude` before the `if`, but also assign a value. (in fact you probably dont even need it to be global)

Comment: You DEFINITLY DONT WANT it to be global.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume (from the error traceback) that your **real** code looks like this:

```
def searchMap(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         # XXX totally unrelated but : __NEVER__ use mutable globals
         # in  a django app.
         global latitude
         global longitude
         city_name = request.POST.get('address')
         city_name_Url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
         address"+city_name
         city_name_Url_Quote=urllib.parse.quote(city_name_Url,':?=/')
         response=urlopen(city_name_Url_Quote).read().decode('utf-8')
         response_json = json.loads(response)


        latitude = response_json.get('results')[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        longitude = api_response_dict('results')[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] 

    return render(request,'WebPage1.html',{'Latitude':latitude,'Longitude':longitude})
```

Now ask yourself what happens when the request's method is not POST... Yes, everything in the `if` block is ignored, and only the last statement (`return render(...)`) is executed. At this point, neither `latitude` nor `longitude` have been defined, hence your error.

The first thing to fix is the use of a POST request for a search. POST is used to update the server's state. A search does not change the server's state (at least it should not, and your's doesn't indeed) so the correct verb here is GET. As an added bonus, it will make your search result page bookmarkable.

So first change your template code to use `GET` as value for your form's `method` attribute. Then in your view, don't test on the request method at all and look for querystring args in `request.GET`. Also, you'll want to handle the case where the user didn't actually send anything:

```
def searchMap(request):
    context = {}
    city_name = request.GET.get('address', '').strip()
    if city_name:
        # hint: use the `python-requests` module instead,
        # it will make you life much easier
        city_name_Url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
        address"+city_name
        city_name_Url_Quote=urllib.parse.quote(city_name_Url,':?=/')
        response=urlopen(city_name_Url_Quote).read().decode('utf-8')
        response_json = json.loads(response)
        context["Latitude"] = response_json.get('results')[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        context["Longitude"] = api_response_dict('results')[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] 
    else:
       # here you want to display an error message to
       # the user - don't forget to check the case
       # in your template. Note that it would be simpler 
       # using a Django Form...
       context["error"] = "Some errorr message here"

    return render(request,'WebPage1.html',context)
```

Comment: But I dont know how can I get latitude and longitude in html from context.

Comment: @ZPC just the same way you did before - except that now they might not be set so you'll have to check in the template (and check for an "error" key too). Note that the snippet I posted is still quite brittle - ie there's no error handling around the `urlopen` call etc and you can be sure this part will break sometimes... but now it's your job to handle this.